# Using strcat to generate list of strings - how to include spaces?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to store variable and constraint names in a MATLAB struct. In order to do this, I tried the following:

```
JiSet = 1:6; nF = length(JiSet);
P.names.con(1:nF,1) = cellstr(strcat('x position for robot ',int2str(JiSet(:))));
```

Seems simple enough, right? Apparently not, because I get the following output:

```
'x position for robot1'
'x position for robot2'
'x position for robot3'
'x position for robot4'
'x position for robot5'
'x position for robot6'
```

I want a space to appear between the text `robot` and its corresponding number. Apparently `strcat` cuts trailing spaces, how do I make sure they are included? I also tried an approach of the form `['x position for robot ' int2str(JiSet(:))]`, but that doesn't work either since the `int2str` part is a vector so the dimensions don't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `strcat` you could do it using the undocumented function `sprintfc` (Check [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function) for infos) that populates cell arrays with strings:

```
clear
clc

JiSet = 1:6; 
nF = length(JiSet);

P.names.con(1:nF,1) = sprintfc('x position for robot %i',JiSet);

Names = P.names.con;

%// You can combine this step with the former but I leave it like this for clarity purposes

Names = vertcat(Names)

Names = 
    'x position for robot 1'
    'x position for robot 2'
    'x position for robot 3'
    'x position for robot 4'
    'x position for robot 5'
    'x position for robot 6'
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, that also gets rid of that pesky `cellstr(strcat())` construction!

Comment: Awesome! I like that function it comes handy quite often :)

Comment: Nice! I learned something useful today. Gonna tuck this away in my bag of tricks, right next to ismembc

Comment: haha yes @Setsu `ismembc` is quite helpful as well! +1 for you also btw :)

Answer (score 2):

Make the first argument a cell.

```
JiSet = 1:6; nF = length(JiSet);
P.names.con(1:nF,1) = cellstr(strcat({'x position for robot '},int2str(JiSet(:))));
```

Gives the output:

```
>> P.names.con
ans = 
    'x position for robot 1'
    'x position for robot 2'
    'x position for robot 3'
    'x position for robot 4'
    'x position for robot 5'
    'x position for robot 6'
```

From the documentation:

```
For cell array inputs, strcat does not remove trailing white space.
```

Comment: Thank you! I saw this somewhere earlier but it didn't seem to work, but I guess I did something wrong then. I accepted the other answer as it yields a shorter syntax, but this one definitely works as well so +1.